# Issues installing node modules with Yarn on Parallels (Windows 10)

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, parallels

I needed to switch an Electron project from a native Windows 10 to a virtual Windows 10 machine on Mac OS with Parallels (Developer). The Nodejs and Yarn installation went smooth, but when I try to install / yarn the node modules of the project I get a bunch of errors which seem to be related to the directory structure of the virtual machine.

```
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/6] ⡀ core-js
[2/6] ⡀ core-js
[3/6] ⡀ node-sass
[4/6] ⡀ deasync
error \\mac\Home\Documents\Development\theproject\node_modules\deasync: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: \\mac\Home\Documents\Development\theproject\node_modules\deasync
Output:
"\\mac\Home\Documents\Development\theproject\node_modules\deasync"
```

In addition CMD.EXE throws the error (summarized since it is in German) that UNC-Paths are not supported and that the path is set to Windows. And because of that I guess the following

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\build.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
```

I am not sue, if both problems have the same reason, the unsupported UNC-path and how to fix this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You may naturally have problems with resolving exotic paths in Node. This includes symbolic links but can also be applied to UNC. In case of binary deps you may want to avoid compilation, try to use deasync version that has a binary for currently used Node version, https://github.com/abbr/deasync-bin . The same may be applicable to nodesass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off Desktop/Folder sharing in Parallels plus installing node-sass manually with `yarn add --dev node-sass` solved the problem.